# Return if route has Tolls Google Maps API xml request

Tags: xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the Standard google maps direction search it has advisory before the directions are written stating this route has tolls. If there are no tolls no advisory shows. I have a google maps api request that is displaying the map with travel distance and duration from 1 home address to 1 work address. I am having difficulty finding where I can return a value through xml on whether the route has tolls. In the api request I can specify to avoid tolls but not return a   confirmation if there is a toll on the route. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm afraid this information isn't available. Usually there will be a notice in the instructions of the steps, but it would be hard to parse these instructions, especially when you haven't set the language-parameter of the API. You may send a feature-request to google, this would be a really useful feature.

Answer (score 4):

Should work, but I'm not guaranteeing that google will alert you to every toll road or not. I'd assume they could, their streetview cars having traveled every single one of them I'm sure they do know where they all are.

```
<?php

$requestUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Milwaukee,WI&destination=Rolling+Meadows,IL&sensor=false';
$response = file_get_contents($requestUrl);
 //note I'm assuming English language
$hasTolls = (strpos($response, 'Toll road') !== false);
var_dump($hasTolls);

?>
```

EDIT:
In fact, it may be useful to report the number of toll roads:

```
<?php

$requestUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Milwaukee,WI&destination=Rolling+Meadows,IL&sensor=false';
$response = file_get_contents($requestUrl);
 //note I'm assuming English language
$numTolls = substr_count($response, 'Toll road');
$hasTolls = ($numTolls > 0);
var_dump($hasTolls);
if ($hasTolls) {
    echo '<p>The route has '.$numTolls.' toll roads</p>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Beware that "Partial toll road" is also a toll road and it would not be counted by these case sensitive functions!

Comment: Also adding language=en to the query string would be a bit more fail safe if you're checking for English words.

Comment: Is it possible to get "toll status" by using source and destination with their latitude , longitude ? Since this is not working properly for few of the routes in India.